# Mixed display-line-numbers-type for evil users?

Tags: evil, line-numbers

I want something like:

`(setq display-line-numbers-type 'mixed)`

Which count wrapped line as "relative", and count folded line as "visual"

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

Say I have a file with contents:

```
first line
second line is so long that need to be wrapped
* third line is a title
cat is cat
* fifth line is a title
dog is dog
```

---

- When (setq display-line-numbers-type t)

```
1 first line
2 second line is so long that need to be
  wrapped
3 * third line is a title
5 * fifth line is a title
```

- When (setq display-line-numbers-type 'relative)

```
0 first line
1 second line is so long that need to be
  wrapped
2 * third line is a title
4 * fifth line is a title
```

- When (setq display-line-numbers-type 'visual)

```
0 first line
1 second line is so long that need to be
2 wrapped
3 * third line is a title
4 * fifth line is a title
```

- However, I want this behavior:

```
0 first line
1 second line is so long that need to be
  wrapped
2 * third line is a title
3 * fifth line is a title
```

Comment: The question is maybe understandable, but a little more detail might help...